# Menu does not show up in Android studio

Tags: java, android, xml

This is my  AndroidManifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="k.coursera.mylocation">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />  
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".test"></activity>
    </application>   

</manifest>
```

When I tried to change the theme to:

```
android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
```

The menu will show up but the other function of my act wouldn't work (such as start a new activity).

And here is the piece of code for my menu XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/deleteCountry" android:title="delete" />
</menu>
```

And my java code:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {    
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.deleteCountry:
            mAdapter.removeAll();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);  
    }
}
```

Comment: ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar requires the v7 AppCompat  library, have you put this in your  code ?

Comment: I just checked the gradle build is 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'    I think this is v7

Comment: It doesnt work tho...

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? The `mAdapter.removeAll()` method is not getting called? Only when you set the theme to `ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar`?

Comment: Also, `ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar` is not meant to be an `Application` or `Activity` level theme, it is an *overlay* meant for an [`AppBarLayout`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/AppBarLayout.html). What are you attempting to achieve with that theme?